# Adding a new enum without breaking existing code

Tags: c++, clang

I have an enum with one undefined and two user values:

```
class enum E
{
    UNDEFINED,
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2
};
```

I want to add `VALUE3` but I'm worried there's a lot of code like:

```
assert(val != E::UNDEFINED);
if(val == E::VALUE1)
{
}
else
{
    // Without an assert this wrongly assumes E::VALUE2
}
```

and:

```
something = (val == E::VALUE1) ? a : b; // last part assumes E::VALUE2
```

I like that compilers warn against switch statements not handling all enumerations and wondered if there is anything similar to show all instances of the above?

I'm concerned I won't find and update all instances of the above.

Compiler is Clang

Comment: Often you'll see the sentinel value (e.g. `UNDEFINED`) at the end just for this reason (`assert(val < E::UNDEFINED)`) but as far as that default `else` case, shame on that developer for assuming, always be explicit in the case you are expecting to handle.

Comment: enums are not restricted to the values you give names to in general. Even if you do not add a value you aren't protected against misuse.

Comment: There's no magical solution here, the compiler has no way to tell if an `if` chain intentionally doesn't handle some of the enumerators or not. Grep (or something else) for all the uses of the enum in an `if`, and convert the ones that need to handle all enumerators to `switch`. If you really want to, use libclang to parse your sources and find all such `if`s.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you elaborate on the last bit? Not familiar with libclang parsing

Comment: Me neither, I just know it's possible. But it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are not restricted to the values you give names to. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) (formatting is mine):

> An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to a range of values (see below for details),
>
> which may include several explicitly named constants ("enumerators"). The values of the constants are values of an integral type known as the underlying type of the enumeration.

The "below details" explain how the enums underlying type is determined. Out of this range we (usually) give names only to some values as in:

```
enum foo {A,B,C};

int main() {
    foo x = static_cast<foo>(42);
}
```

This code is completely fine. `x` has an underlying value of `42`. There is no name for the value but this doesn't really matter... unless you assume that it does.

That wrong assumption is made by this code:

```
assert(val != E::UNDEFINED);
if(val == E::VALUE1)
{
}
else
{
    // Without an assert this wrongly assumes E::VALUE2
}
```

This code is what needs to be fixed (independent of whether you add a new named constant to the enum or not).

---

Now for a more serious trial to answer the question...

---

There is no way to get a warning when a chain of `if-else` does not cover all enum values. What you can do is to turn all `if-else` uses of the enum into errors. Consider what actually happens here:

```
if (x == E::VALUE1) do_something();

switch(x) {
    case E::VALUE1 : return 1;
}
```

In the if statement we call `operator==(foo,foo);` its return value either is a `bool` or is implicitly converted to one. With the switch none of this is needed. We can make use of this to turn `if-else` usages of the enum into errors. Bear with me I will explain in two steps. First lets create a compiler error for `if( x == E::VALUE1)`:

```
class helper { 
    operator bool(){ return false;} 
};

helper operator==(E,E){ 
    return {}; 
}
```

Now `if (x == E::VALUE1)` calls `helper operator==(E,E)`, thats fine. Then the result is converted to `bool`, and that fails because the conversion is `private`. Using the enum in a switch is still ok and you can rely on compiler errors / warnings. The basic idea is just to have something that only fails to compile when called (in the wrong/right context). ([Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v8c7bd)).

The drawback is that also all other used of `operator==` are broken. We can fix them by modifying the helper and the call sites:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum E {VALUE1};

struct helper { 
    bool value; 
private:
    operator bool(){ return false;} 
};

helper operator==(E a,E b){ 
    return {
        static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(a) == static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(b)
    }; 
}

int main() {
    E x{VALUE1};
    //if ( x== E::VALUE1); // ERROR
    bool is_same = (x == E::VALUE1).value;

    switch(x) {
        case E::VALUE1 : return 1;
    }
}
```

Yes it is a major inconvenience to have to write `.value`, but in this way you can turn all uses of the enum in `if`s into errors while everything else will still compile. Also note that you have to make sure to cover all cases you want to catch (eg `!=`,`<`, etc).

Comment: It *may* not work for the OP, but it's definitely an answer :)

Comment: For a wee moment, I considered flagging this as "Not an answer" ... but I changed my mind! ‎ Maybe we should add a "NANA" flag to the system?

Comment: I'm thinking of converting to switch statements. Is it possible for compilers to give warnings when using IF/ELSE IF on enums? Or not because they're just integers?

Comment: @AdrianMole I added a more serious part, still not satisfied myself, but unless someone comes up with something better ... :P

Comment: @user997112 I dont know a good answer to your question. My idea would be to turn all uses of the enum into errors (see edit) and then fix them one by one

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah, only way really

Comment: @user997112 I see that it might seem reasonable for compilers to be able to work this out, they do some pretty magical things. But this particular case I think we are a long way from seeing :(

Comment: @user997112 i edit with something better. You cannot get errors / warnings for incomplete `if-else` usage but with some effort you can turn all `if-else` uses into errors